# Google Controls and dashboards - Change place holder value

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

I need to change the default place holder value of the Google charts category filter. Can any one specify how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer for my need. Adding the following property in the options saw me home.

```
 var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control2',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Project',
        'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'caption':'Select Project',
          'allowTyping': true,
          'allowMultiple': true
        }
      }
    });
```

The caption property did the trick.